# Random (lldb) crashes in iOS Simulator on Mac OS X 10.8.4

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, lldb

I've been struggling with an weird issue for some time now. When running my app with the iOS Simulator initially closed it launches correctly. But if I then run it again without closing the simulator it crashes and just prints (lldb) in the error log. If I then run it again (without closing the simulator) it launches correctly. And if I do the same again it crashes. So it seems to be every second time. It works when using a iOS device and I have a college with the exact same project who doesn't experience this problem in the iOS Simulator. What I've tried is cleaning, reset contents and settings, manually removing the app, restarting my computer and reinstalling Xcode.

Comment: This bug should be reported to apple. Its irritating.

Comment: As noted in the answer below, this issue is fixed in the Xcode 4.6.3 update, just released.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's an issue with OS X 10.8.4 that causes random simulator crashes.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/817179#817179

A couple of workarounds have been suggested, including switching to GDB. See here:

> We have found the issue. It is a process killing race condition in
>   "debugserver" when it is killing the application it is debugging which
>   causes this problem to occur.
>
> The work around that should work for
>   all folks is to kill the app first, wait for it to go away, then hit
>   CMD+R. The quick turn around of just pressing CMD+R is now showing
>   this thread race condition more often in 10.8.4.

Comment: Oh, that probably it then. My college haven't updated to the last version of OSX but I have. Thank you for the fast reply, saves me a lot of work!

Comment: no bother. Glad to help! It was a bit of luck as I just saw some chat on this last night on Mike Hay's twitter https://twitter.com/Hay

Comment: It was a great work around, but you don't need change to GDB any more.. it was resolved by apple as noted.

Answer (score 5):

Apple resolved this issue in June 13th, 2013 build:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I meet it too. In Product -> edit scheme   change the debugger from lldb to gdb. Can simply solve it. Hope Apple can fix it asap.