# xcode run app and crash without error(only lldb). Why?

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, lldb

each time I run my app it would crash.
However, i run again after crash, it would not crash again and the app can run normally.

whats wrong with it?

[image]

i have the random error after i add a UIView that implemented the drawRect method.
can anyone help???

I try separated my program.

after implementing the drawRect method  cause the radom error and crash.
But i hav any idea about Y it would happen.....
Can anyone help me?? pls

StickView.m

```
#import "StickView.h"

@implementation StickView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    UIBezierPath *rectPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];

    [rectPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    [rectPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0 + self.bounds.size.width, 0)];
    [rectPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0 + self.bounds.size.width, 0 + self.bounds.size.height)];
    [rectPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0 + self.bounds.size.height)];
    [rectPath closePath];   

    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [rectPath stroke];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;

}
```

and I just call a property of StickView and add it onto my ViewController:

ViewController.m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

#import "StickView.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()
@end
@implementation DetailViewController

-(StickView *)stickView
{
    if (!_stickView) {
        _stickView = [[StickView alloc] init];
    }
    return _stickView;
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: There is a known bug in OSX 10.8.4 where the debugger will hang. Here is a post about the bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957602/random-lldb-crashes-in-ios-simulator-on-mac-os-x-10-8-4

Comment: It is the bug due to the MAC system? 
So i dont need to implement my app? right?

Comment: As was noted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957602/random-lldb-crashes-in-ios-simulator-on-mac-os-x-10-8-4 today, Xcode 4.6.3 was released with a fix for this issue.